# Proving $t=(1+\sqrt{1+2hg/v^2 } )  (v/g)$ for a thrown ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, kinematics

If we throw a ball from the hight point $h$ from the earth, with initial velocity  $v’$, how to prove that the time it takes the ball to reach the earth is given by:

$$t=\frac{v}{g}(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2hg}{v^2} } )$$

Comment: You work with the equations of motion. BTW, is this a homework type problem?

Comment: Why the question was tagged as a homework ? It's not

Comment: Did you check the homework tag [description](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info)?

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry no,but i know that you shouldn't tag the question as a homework unless if the OP say that blatantly.

Comment: I'm just trying to get a decision either way. If you think the homework tag does not apply, please edit it out again.

Comment: @rib This won't work -- hard core do-my-job OPs will never admit their question is a homework problem.

Answer (score 2):

For a free falling object without air resistance you have two equations

$$ y = h + v'\,t - \frac{1}{2} g t^2 $$
  $$ v = v' - g\,t $$

with $h$ the initial height, $v'$ the initial velocity (upwards is positive), $y$ the height at time $t$, and $v$ the velocity.

Solve them when $y=0$ for $v$ and $t$.

Reference: [projectile motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

Comment: equations should be $ v_{f}=V_{0}+gt $ and $ h=v_{0} t+1/gt^{2} $ the equation for the high is a second order equation yu can solve it immediatly for 't'